# Can I call two crossdomain.xml from two different servers from my flash player?

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml

crossdomain.xml, quite a simple concept which most of the developers might have came through, though just for info :-

> A cross-domain policy file is an XML document that grants a web client, such as Adobe Flash Player or Adobe Acrobat (though not necessarily limited to these), permission to handle data across domains. When clients request content hosted on a particular source domain and that content make requests directed towards a domain other than its own, the remote domain needs to host a cross-domain policy file that grants access to the source domain, allowing the client to continue the transaction.

Secure HLS streaming :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html

The question :

I have a flash hls player (player.swf) that is on my site www.A.com. Now the request is being made to a media server www.B.com/playlist.m3u8 which is a secure hls request (AES-128 encrypted). The key url contained in playlist.m3u8 points to a web server www.C.com/keyPage.jsp

Now my player.swf ideally should call crossdomain.xml for both the servers while calling them and proceed with the subsequent calls, though in my case once the player receive the second crossdomain.xml from www.C.com it stops making any other call. However if I move the key delivery application from www.C.com to www.A.com it works fine.

I am really confused on such a behavior as according to the documents crossdomain.xml is used by destination server to validate a client which resides on some other server.So how does it matter if I am using multiple servers and providing crossdomain xml for all of them for a single flash application.

P.S. - I have tried the same process with different online hls players available and everyone of them depicts the same behavior

**EDIT 1**
Just for reference my crossdomain xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
     <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
     <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Could you put an online example to see that behavior ?

Comment: Also dont mix access of SSL with non-SSL servers. They must all load from a `http...` or all from `https...`. Secondly why cant your key be at **A.com** anyway? Or else have the page at **A.com** simply load the player.swf & key (both being stored at **C.com**).

Comment: @akmozo - I don't think that might be possible.

Comment: @VC. One - Ya I am taking care of that everything should load from either http or https and not a mix. It is not feasible for me to have my key at A or C.com because of security reasons. So can I call two crossdomain xmls is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Can you post the crossdomain from the C server ? Most likely the player is blocked once and does not make any subsequent calls. Also make sure the C Server doesn't block ports or connections (firewall?)

Comment: @Philarmon - I don't think that the player is being blocked by the server as the server is delivering the crossdomain xml in response with the status of 200.

Comment: Sure, the player will get the crossdomain file. I mean being blocked for security reasons - you know, if the crossdomain have something that wouldn't allow to connect. I remember having something like that in the past - I believe in this case all further calls will be skipped (or at least they are not showing up in the browser log).

Comment: @Philamon : The crossdomain xml I am using will basically allow anyone to access from that server. I am putting my crossdomain xml in edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after too much digging into the issue, I figured out that the problem was coming because **C.com** is a jboss server. I tried the same architecture replacing C.com first by IIS and then Apache tomcat. In both the cases all the calls are being requested and served properly.

So the above question **if i can request for 2 crossdomain xmls of two different servers from my flash player** is **yes, I can do that**.

**Though still the question remains why providing the crossdomain xml from jboss stops the subsequent calls**